# SEO Implications Of Canonical Link Requiring Login

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical

Is it considered bad practice for a canonical link on a page return a `302` redirect to a login page?

Example:

If `https://foo.com/bar/slug?version=2019-02-01&signature=XXX` returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://foo.com/bar/slug" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

but `https://foo.com/bar/slug` returns

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://foo.com/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fbar%2Fslug
```

A) Is this considered bad practice?

B) If the url with the querystring returns the `200` will it's content still be indexed if a search engine crawls it?

c) If a search engine crawls multiple variants of the querystring version (`/bar/slug?version=2019-02-01&signature=XXX`, `/bar/slug?version=2019-02-02&signature=YYY`, `/bar/slug?version=2019-02-03&signature=ZZZ`) will search engines only "keep" the most recent version (assuming I set `Last-Modified` headers to match the date in the querystring version and they all have the same canonical link) indexed?